# "Kabuki" in end credits of Avatar: The Way of Water

Tags: credits, avatar-the-way-of-water

The end credits of [Avatar: The Way of Water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar:_The_Way_of_Water) are split into different sections, and one of these sections is titled `Kabuki`.

This surprises many Japanese viewers ([1](https://eiga.com/movie/87901/review/02938892/), [2](https://movies.yahoo.co.jp/movie/382617/review/dbf742ee-0731-4f7a-af0f-75a0ebf7676f/)) and me.

What does this `Kabuki` section contains?
Is there any connection to the [classical form of Japanese dance-drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabuki)?

---

Not sure whether that matters, but James Cameron seems to know kabuki:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As explained by James Cameron](https://www.provideocoalition.com/exclusive-interview-with-james-cameron-and-the-avatar-2-editorial-team/) in this interview with ProVideo Coalition:

> Jim: And it’s not storyboards, it’s actual shots. At this point, we’re looking at an image that’s probably, I would say about half real, like half or maybe one third of reality, reality being our final goal. But we have what we call Kabuki face.
>
> And **the Kabuki face is a projection map of the actor’s facial performance camera, projection-mapped onto a blank model of the face.** So we actually see the expressions, we hear the dialogue, we see eyes flicking from one character to another. We see everything we need to see from an editorial standpoint and it’s the characters, actually. all up fully clothed with all their props in the environment, properly lit with shadows, with smoke, fire, rain, all that sort of thing. It’s just not photoreal yet, but it’s a shot. It’s not previs, it’s an actual shot and it’s the actual performance.